# Calculating $\cosh \big( i \ln(3)\big)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> $$\cosh \big( i \ln(3)\big)$$

**My attempt:**

$$=\frac{e^{i\ln 3}+e^{-i \ln 3}}{2}$$

$$=\frac{e^{i}e^{\ln 3}+e^{-i}e^{ \ln 3}}{2}$$

$$=\frac{e^{i}3+e^{-i}3}{2}$$

$$=\frac{3(e^{i}+e^{-i})}{2}$$

$$=\frac 3 2 (e^i+e^{-i})$$

But the answer should be $\color{blue}{\cos(\ln 3)}$

Comment: $e^{i \ln 3 } \neq e^i e^{\ln 3}$

Comment: I done a stupid mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$2\cos(y)=e^{(iy)}+e^{(-iy)}=e^{(iy)}+e^{-(iy)}=2\cosh(iy)$$

as $$2\cosh(u)=e^u+e^{-u}$$

Comment: In what is this different from my answer? You just started the other way around.

Comment: @egreg, No basic difference. I thought this method will be more lucid

Comment: So it should just be a comment. Of course you're free to think differently.

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$
e^{ix}\ne e^ie^x
$$
but rather
$$
e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x
$$
So
$$
\cosh(ix)=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}=
\frac{\cos x+i\sin x+\cos(-x)+i\sin(-x)}{2}=\cos x
$$